# How to find “Android class name” in “AndroidManifest.xml” generated by Air mobile

Tags: android, xml, facebook, actionscript-3, air

I create Facebook app and it requires **Android Class Name** in setting. Could you please

tell me how to find class name and package name in air mobile?

[image]

Morover, This is my `application.xml`

```
<android>
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:enabled="true">

<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.DialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>

 </application>
 </manifest>]]></manifestAdditions></android>
```

My document class ( main class ) is located in `src/Main.as`.

My facebook ane is [com.freshplanet.AirFacebook](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really matter what you use as long as you sign it with the same package. You could use `com.freshplanet` for package and `com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.DialogActivity` for your class.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use *com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook* as your main package and create *LoginActivity* and *DialogActivity* classes inside that package.